# Where to place async/await in this case?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, xmlhttprequest

**EDIT:**

**The problem was not the placement of the async/await per se, but the fact that I was trying to make a constructor asynchronous.**

---

I have looked through docs, read other questions and answers, but I still can't get my head wrapped around what function to make async, and where to place the await, to get the behaviour that I want.

Basically, I want the `console.log(this.data)` in the constructor to log out the data I fetch, but as it is now it logs out a pending `Promise`.

I have tried literally everything I can think of, I always end up logging out either a `Promise`, or `undefined`.

Where can I add async/await in these methods to make it log out the fetched data in the constructor?

If I'm going at this in the compltetly wrong approach, then please let me know.

```
class Apa {
  
  constructor () {
    
    this.ajaxURL = 'https://example.com/api/';
    this.mockParams = {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    };
    
    this.data = this.getData(this.mockParams).then(xhr => this.data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)).catch(xhr => this.data = {});
    console.log(this.data);
    
  }
  
  getData(params) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let request = this.postAjax(this.ajaxURL, params);
      request.then((xhr) => {
        resolve(xhr);
      }).catch((xhr) => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Ajax request failed: getData()';
        reject(xhr);
      });

    });
    
  }
  
  postAjax(url, data) {
    
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
                function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
            ).join('&');

            var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { resolve(xhr); }
            };
            xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(params);
        });
    
  }
  
}
```

*Note:*
I know the class doesn't work as is, I had to replace the real API endpoints with mock up stuff, but I can ensure you that there is no problems in the calls to the real API. The promise (when resolved) does contain the real XMLHttpRequest with the correct response.

Comment: by the way, there's no need to create a Promise in `getData` as the function `this.postAjax` already returns one

Comment: I don't think a constructor can be `async`, so you won't be able to use async/await, just use promise .then like you already are in the rest of your code

Comment: @JaromandaX That's correct, I got an error trying to async the constructor

Comment: yes, but the `console.log(this.data);` is in the constructor, and will not "wait" for the promises in the previous line to resolve - and you can't use async/await in the constructor (directly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what function to make async

Simple rule: If function contains `await`, it must be marked `async`. It changes the semantics of the function so that its `return` actually becomes resolution of a promise, and will have no traditional return value; it also says execution of parts of it (those following an `await`) will end up being in the future, as opposed to within the current task.

However, you can't delay creation of an object (when constructor returns, it must return a constructed object), so constructor cannot be `async`.

You can still output `this.data` from code that is within constructor, but not at the time the constructor is executing.

Since constructor *must* be synchronous in order to construct the object, and AJAX request *must* be asynchronous(*) in order to give the response time to arrive, I'm letting you know

> If I'm going at this in the compltetly wrong approach, then please let me know.

---

*) This is in fact not true; AJAX call *can* be synchronous (by passing `false` as the third parameter of `xhr.open`), but this is [*heavily* discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback! So would it be better if I for example just call the `getData()` method in the constructor, and then place everything I want to do after the Ajax call returns in the `.then()` for the Promise that that `getData()` returns?

Comment: Yes. Any time you want to use data fetched by AJAX, this should be done either from the callback, or in promise chain, or similar (or alternately with a check to see if data is available, if called independently, with a fallback behaviour if it is not).

Comment: Alright, thank you! I've mostly been working in much more synchronous code on the server side, so I think I've been trying a bit too hard to get the same flow in JS. Your input was very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, always think "this will be in the future". If you have a FedEx package coming, you can: listen for the bell then take the package (promise), tell them to tell you when package arrives and you'll pick it up (callback), or whenever you have a desire to open the package to go out on the porch, look if it's here yet, and open it if it is, and tell yourself to have more patience if not (set a guard around the resource). You can't order something and immediately go open it. As long as you know what happens now and what happens in the future, you should have no issues.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do what you want in your code in the constructor, using async/await, is like this

```
class Apa {

  constructor () {

    this.ajaxURL = 'https://example.com/api/';
    this.mockParams = {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    };
     (async () => {
       this.data = this.getData(this.mockParams).then(xhr => this.data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)).catch(xhr => this.data = {});
       console.log(this.data);
    })();
  }
  ... etc
}
```